# remove all numeric characters from column mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, database

I want to develop one mysql function that can remove only numeric characters from the string.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your code and let us know where you have stucked. We will surely help you.

Comment: http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=233

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a user defined function, where in you can write your logic of replacement or you can try :

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(column,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')
```

Comment: that means if I need to remove characters from string, I will have to write replace 52 (26 for lower and 26 for upper case)??

Comment: NO then we should opt for a udf..it was just an alternative

Comment: Yes Sashi kant It works.. Thanx a Lot for reply.. Can we achieve same solution with any regular expression?

Comment: Note that I wasn't able to make REPLACE(column,'[0-9]+','') work with mysql 5.1.  I didn't try the alternative answer provided.

Comment: Sadly, `mysql`, unlike `postgresql`, does not support regular expression replace out of the box.

Comment: Uh, then you agree that the above answer, as written, is misleading, and should be changed?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ae225/3/1  The statement executes, but it only actually tries to replace the literal string '[0-9]+', which is obviously never going to be found.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, it saved me a lot of typing ;) 
The first one sadly doesn't work though...

Comment: This is kinda trivial. Isn't there a more elegent answer in MySQL?

Answer (score 6):

Create function to achieve this task.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphas; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION alphas( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(16) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ; 
SELECT alphas('123ab45cde6789fg'); 
+----------------------------+ 
| alphas('123ab45cde6789fg') | 
+----------------------------+ 
| abcdefg                    | 
+----------------------------+
```

If you want only digits, use this

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1; 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS digits; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION digits( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(32) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN  
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ; 

SELECT digits('123ab45cde6789fg'); 
+----------------------------+ 
| digits('123ab45cde6789fg') | 
+----------------------------+ 
| 123456789                  | 
+----------------------------+
```

### [Reference](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#815)

Comment: thnx Fahim.. Actually I did not know how to accept the answer..Anyway thnx for help

Comment: @RonakShah : I guessed that as I saw you are new... so sharing that was my job... at start even I was not knowing...