# Need to remove numeric data from row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have millions of data in MySQL table, now I need to update one particular column of the table with only non-numeric characters. That is I need to remove all numbers from that column. The row wont be deleted, only updated with only non-numeric values.

I need some efficient way to achieve this.

Calling 10 times replace doesn't look good.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: It would help if you posted the `create table` for the incriminated table.

Comment: Need more information - are the numbers same, do the columns have a mix of numeric and non numeric values? Some sample of the data would help.

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431831/remove-all-numeric-characters-from-column-mysql

Answer (score -1):

For mysql, you just have to replace everything:

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(column,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','');
```