# Regex and GROUP from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database of companies addresses (street name) like :

```
876 Lexington ave
703 Lexington ave
872 Lexington ave
3501 Jack Northrop Ave
3503 Jack Northrop Ave
3505 Jack Northrop Ave
```

And so on.....

What I am trying to do is `SELECT` a row and `GROUP` them by addresses/street name to get the output like : `Lexington ave, Jack Northrop Ave`.
Goal is to erase the numeric street number and then GROUP them by name.

How can I achieve this with MySQL query? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to remove the characters prior to the first space, you can use `substr` and `instr`:

```
select distinct substr(address, instr(address, ' ') + 1)
from yourtable;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a1d7/1)

---

If there are some street addresses that don't include this prefix, here's another option using  `union all` and `regexp` to combine the results:

```
select distinct address 
from (
  select substr(address, instr(address, ' ') + 1) as address
  from yourtable
  where address regexp '^[0-9]'
  union all
  select address
  from yourtable
  where address not regexp '^[0-9]'
  ) t
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e0ef4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove leading numbers using `trim()`.  So this might do what you want:

```
select distinct trim(leading '0123456789 ' from address) as street_name
from t;
```

Comment: Can we use pattern for LEADING? I guess it was for string only. By the way I tired that query, didn't worked. Thank you though :)

Comment: I don't think this will work, you need to remove one letter at a time like with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431831/remove-all-numeric-characters-from-column-mysql, but of course if there's a 4th Avenue or something it would break it