# How can i sort SQL by number, length & letters?

Tags: mysql, sorting

How should I sort my `SELECT` ?

**EXAMPLE LIST**

```
1, 2, 2A, 4, 10, 10A
```

**SQL**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = '$var' ORDER BY length(column2), column2";
```

If I `ORDER BY length()` like my example, 2A will end up in the bottom.
If I remove `length()`, 10 comes after 1.

How do I sort so it appears as above?

Comment: [Something very similar here, just reverse the String Number calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939518/sorting-string-column-containing-numbers-in-sql). Biggest problem is, you don't know how long the number is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = '$var' ORDER BY CAST(column2 as UNSIGNED), column2";
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

order by hex is best way to do this:

`$query = "SELECT *, cast(hex(column2 as unsigned) as l FROM table WHERE column1 = '$var' ORDER BY l"`;

Answer (score 0):

With a custom function such as `alphas` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431831/remove-all-numeric-characters-from-column-mysql), you can order it by first the number portion of the value followed by the string portion of the value.

If you define and populate a table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE test (t VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ('10A'),
  ('2'),
  ('2A'),
  ('4'),
  ('10'),
  ('1');
```

Then create a custom function called `alphas` which extracts the string portion (no numbers):

```
DELIMITER |
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS alphas; 
CREATE FUNCTION alphas( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(16) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can do a ordered query like this:

```
SELECT t FROM test ORDER BY CAST(t AS UNSIGNED), alphas(t);
```

The `CAST` function converts strings like `10A` to an unsigned number of `10`.