# split mysql column into numeric and chars

Tags: mysql

I have the following column in mysql table:

```
NoRegProp
-------------
NULL
62
135/عرسال
31المنية
التبانة  1132
```

which is not organized at all. I want to separated the numeric values from the string values in 2 different columns as follow:

```
numberReg               placeReg
NULL                    NULL
62                      NULL
135                     عرسال
31                      المنية
1132                    التبانة
```

Please any help?

Comment: If *you* can't identify and describe a pattern to automatically split by, what makes you think we can? We know much less about your data than we do.

Comment: i used this query to extract the numeric values, but i don't know how to extract the string values:
`code`UPDATE CARMDI SET `numberReg` = CONVERT( `NoRegProp` , SIGNED INTEGER );`code`

Comment: you did it for integer and now for string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431831/remove-all-numeric-characters-from-column-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   cast(NoRegProp as signed) as numberReg, 
   substring(NoRegProp, CHAR_LENGTH(cast(NoRegProp as signed)) + 1,  CHAR_LENGTH(NoRegProp)) as placeReg 
from yourtablename
```

For String sanitizing(removing / etc) you can further use REPLACE

Comment: this query is good but it won't give a good result if i have this format : 65/75حالات  , it returns numberReg = 65 ; placeReg = /75حالات  , which i need only the placeReg  = حالات

Comment: consider doing replace before cast - replace(NoRegProp, '/', '')